# addhandler in EditingControlShowing in vb net

Tags: vb.net

I have this code in DataGridView_EditingControlShowing

```
    If TypeOf e.Control Is ComboBox Then
        With DirectCast(e.Control, ComboBox)
            .DropDownStyle = ComboBoxStyle.DropDown
            .AutoCompleteMode = AutoCompleteMode.SuggestAppend
            .AutoCompleteSource = AutoCompleteSource.ListItems
            .DroppedDown = False
        End With
        AddHandler e.Control.KeyDown, AddressOf cell_KeyDown      
    End If
```

i want addhandler when press key to make (DirectCast(e.Control, ComboBox).DroppedDown = False )
but its addressof refer to outer sub where i cant use the e.control . because e.control only works with DataGridView_EditingControlShowing event sub 
Any Solution ?

Comment: Is there a reason you cant pass `e` or `e.Control` to the "outer sub"?

Comment: @Plutonix, because what he's referring to as the "outer sub" is an event handler and so you don't get to pass anything to it directly.

Answer (score 0):

If you are adding a handler to the `KeyDown` event of the object currently referenced by `e.Control` then, in that handler, that same object will be the `sender`.  The object raising the event is ALWAYS provided via the `sender` parameter.  That means that, in your `cell_KeyDown` method, you need to do this:

```
DirectCast(sender, ComboBox).DroppedDown = False
```